# mysqli_fetch_assoc() returning data twice

Tags: php, mysqli

I recently decided to test my really old project that I had with the newer version of PHP, so I had to switch from `mysql_fetch_assoc()` to `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`.

However, on running it on my localhost the data is being returned two times.

Here is the code snippet. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance :)

```
<?php
$query = 'SELECT people_id, people_fullname FROM people WHERE people_isactor = 1 ORDER BY people_fullname;';
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query)  or die(mysqli_error($con));

//populate the select options with the result
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    foreach($row as $value){
        if($row['people_id'] == $movie_leadactor){
            echo '<option value="'.$row['people_id'].'"selected="selected">';
        }else{
            echo '<option value="'.$row['people_id'].'">';
        }
        echo $row['people_fullname'].'<option>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You are looping through each row with `foreach`! Yes, that'll output everything as many times as there are fields in the row.

Comment: It seems strange that this wouldn't have done the same thing before you updated it to use mysqli instead.

Comment: 1.remove `foreach` only (not if-else inside it).2 `echo $row['people_fullname'].'<option>';` tis line have no sense

Comment: @AlivetoDie I think it sort of makes sense, it's just missing the `/` for the closing tag, right?

Comment: @Don'tPanic  you are right, but it's a bad way to do so

Comment: Even i wonder how it worked back then and not now? :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Remove `foreach()`

2.Last`<option>` need to be `</option>`.

Do like below:-

```
<?php
$query = 'SELECT people_id, people_fullname FROM people WHERE people_isactor = 1 ORDER BY people_fullname;';
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query)  or die(mysqli_error($con));

//populate the select options with the result
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    if($row['people_id'] == $movie_leadactor){
        echo '<option value="'.$row['people_id'].'"selected="selected">'.$row['people_fullname'].'</option>';
    }else{
        echo '<option value="'.$row['people_id'].'">'.$row['people_fullname'].'</option>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @ArunKumar  glad to help you.